# display short animation when connecting the plug charge & when unplug the charger in nokia e72, Symbian s60

Tags: symbian, nokia

how to display a short animation when connecting the plug charge & when unplug the charger ?

Answer (score 0):

To detect changes in charger connection state, use `CTelephony::GetIndicator()` to get notifications on `CTelephony::EBatteryInfoChange` events. Of particular interest are `TBatteryStatus` changes in the `TBatteryInfoV1` object.

To get started with animation, search the SDK documentation for "animation".